# Apache Jmeter Load Test to achieve that only one thread starts until test achieve the desired number of users

Tags: jmeter

I have implemented a testplan in Apache Jmeter to measure how the system serves the request with XY users.

Steps:

- User Login via a web browser with username and password
- After the login, user click on the given link which starts a job on the server

When I configure thread group with the GIVEN number of users I can see the Jmeter stars thread within the given time range. Like this:

1. 1 user --> starts 1 job
2. 2 users --> starts 1 + 1 job
3. 3 users --> starts 1 + 1 + 1 job
   ...
   So When the test ends I have 6 started job instead of 3 :(

**So my question is:**

How it is possible that every time starts only one job within the given time range to achieve the predefined user number?

For example:

- If I have 10 users I would like to see only 10 started jobs at the end of the test.
- If I have 100 users I would like to see only 100 started
  jobs at the end of the test

Here is the Expected Active Users Count, where you can see that when the test achieved the 10 users there are more than desired job started because the active users' number increased +1 after the previous thread ends.

[Expected Active Users Count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ftxB.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to execute a job by a user **only once** it's better to consider switching to the "normal" [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configured like:

[image]

If you want to continue using the Ultimate Thread Group - put your request(s) which trigger the job creation under the [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller), but in this case you will see a lot of error messages in the jmeter.log file (which can be [supressed](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) if you're fine with this approach)